# Why is a completely random measure mixing?

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory, poisson-process, mixing, point-processes

Let $S_x$ denote an operator on $\mathcal{M}_{\chi}^{\#}$ by $S_x\xi(\cdot)=\xi(\cdot+x)$, where $\xi$ is a random measure. Here, $\mathcal{M}_{\chi}^{\#}$ refers to the space of boundedly finite measures on $\chi$, and $\mathcal{N}_{\chi}^{\#}$ refers to the space of boundedly finite counting measures on $\chi$.

A stationary random measure (respectively, point process) on state space $\chi=\mathbb{R}^d$ is said to be *mixing* if for all $V,W$ in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{M}_\chi^{\#})$ (respectively, $\mathcal{N}_\chi^{\#})$ we have $P(S_xV \cap W)-P(V)P(W) \to 0$, where $P$ is the probability measure of the random measure.

It is claimed in page 207 of [this textbook](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-387-49835-5) (springer link) that any completely random measure such as the Poisson process clearly satisfies this mixing property.

Why is this claim true?